# How to use logical operator in Python as compared to PHP in integers?

Tags: php, python-3.x

I have 2 blocks of code,

**test.php** -->

```
$a = 90;
$b = 87;
$c = $a AND $b;
print_r($c);
----------------------
OUTPUT -->
----------------------
90
```

**test.py** -->

```
a = 90
b = 87
c= a and b
print(c)
----------------------
OUTPUT -->
----------------------
87
```

Now, As I understand both PHP and python when executing the code, interpret the code down to C to machine level (which is the parent language of both)

Then why are they both behaving differently?

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: They behave differently because they are two *different* languages. Just because there seems to be some similar syntax doesn't mean the behavior have to be similar. You have to read the documentation of each language to find out exactly what each language is doing.

Comment: In python `and` is same as php `&&`. And php `&&` is not the same as php `AND`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not saying they should behave similarly, I'm asking if on machine-level code is getting interpreted in the same language, then why are they behaving differently?

Comment: @u_mulder so Thanks it was helpful! then what is the equivalent of PHP's ```and``` in Python?

Comment: C is not machine level code

Comment: If the behavior of the operators are different, then the interpreters executing the code will perform different operations, and the CPU instructions will of course be different as well. But the important bit you forget here is that both languages are generally *interpreted* by other programs. The behavior of the languages are removed from the behavior of any direct CPU instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code

```
$a = 90;
$b = 87;
$c = $a AND $b;
```

is the same as (thanks to operators precedence):

```
$a = 90;
$b = 87;
($c = $a) AND $b;
```

So, you just **assign** `$a` to `$c`, and `$b`... It does nothing.

As for python code:

```
a = 90
b = 87
c = a and b
print(c)
```

Python iterpreter **returns last value** if condition is `True`. So `c` is **87**. If you write

```
c = b and a
print(c)
```

you will see **90**. Whoa!

So, if you want same results, the codes should be:

```
$a = 90;
$b = 87;
$c = $a && $b;
var_dump($c);   // bool(true)
```

and:

```
a = 90
b = 87
c = bool(a and b)
print(c)        // True
```

I assume that you want to check that **both** variables `a` and `b` are truthy.